# PHP How to setup a script to take two number values from two fields add them and update into 3rd field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with various fields 2 of which contain a number between 1 and 50.

I need help setting up a script that will automatically take two set fields add them and insert the total into a third field for each indivdual record for all records in the table.

I'm stuck in creating this because some records will have 0  or NULL values.

Please help :)

I've think I may be able to do this purely in SQL but the closest i found was this:

```
Alter table Mytable add column Keywords varchar(255);
update Mytable set Keywords = concat(Categories, ' ', Tags);
```

Obviously I would not need to add the column etc. Either a PHP or SQL solution would be fantastic.

Example in case I'mm not explaining this well it's confusing me a lot

```
Column 1 - Field Value: 20
Colum 2 - Field Value 20
Add Colum 1 + Colum 2 = 40
Insert 40 into Colum 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET col3 = [TABLE_NAME].col1 + [TABLE_NAME].col2;
```

Replace [TABLE_NAME] and col1, col2, col3 with your tables and columns

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`UPDATE Mytable SET column3 = column2 + column1`

this should work for 0 , however if you have got NULL values in any of the 
 adding column you will get a NULL in  the result field, so in that case the query is slightly different

for e.g. if 
 Column1 may have null values, then the query should be

`UPDATE Mytable  SET column3 = IFNULL(column1 ,0) + column2`

and if both the fields can have NULL values then,

`UPDATE Mytable  SET column3 = IFNULL(column1 ,0) + IFNULL(column2 ,0)`

Comment: Great stuff it worked perfectly... thank you! I definatley need to learn a little more about SQL itself and stop worrying about php so much.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in plain SQL.

If both columns are stored as numbers:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET `Column 3` = IFNULL(`Column 1`,0) + IFNULL(`Column 2`,0)
```

If they are stored as characters:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET `Column 3` = CAST(IFNULL(`Column 1`,0) AS SIGNED)
               + CAST(IFNULL(`Column 2`,0) AS SIGNED)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE your_table SET Column3 = Column1+Column2
```

or

```
UPDATE your_table SET Column3 = IFNULL ( Column1, 0 ) + Column2
```

to avoid NULs on Column1